# Dart json serializable - decode value as different type

Tags: json, dart, json-deserialization

Let's say I'm building an app that receives a json as a response, for example:

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Let's say I want to parse this json into the following class:

```
class Example {
  String a;
  List<String> b;
}
```

Using Dart's `json_serializable` package I can do the following

```
String intToString(int value) => value.toString();
List<String> intToStringList(List<int> value) => value.map(intToString).toList();

@JsonSerializable()
class Example {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: intToString)
  String a;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: intToStringList)
  List<String> b;

  Example(this.a, this.b);

  factory Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ExampleFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleToJson(this);
}
```

My question is if there is any built in, more elegant way to do this without custom method implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cleanest way I found of doing this is using a `JsonConverter`:

```
class StringListFromIntListConverter implements JsonConverter<List<String>, List<int>> {
  const StringListFromIntListConverter();

  @override
  List<String> fromJson(List<int> json) => json.map((num) => num.toString()).toList()

  @override
  List<int> toJson(List<String> object) => object.map((str) => int.parse(str)).toList();
}
```

Then use this converter wherever is needed like this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
@StringListFromIntListConverter()
class Example {
  String a;
  List<String> b;

  Example(this.a, this.b);

  factory Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ExampleFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleToJson(this);
}
```

This will automatically deserialize and serialize string lists in this class to and from int lists.
The nice thing is that this can be implemented for every type and reused in different places.

Found this really useful for time and durations objects that are received as some kind of number and I want my members to be the actual type I need.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the problem is in the implementation of the generator. I tried another generator and there is also no other way.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:object_serializer/json_serializer_generator.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

void main() {
  final classes = loadYaml(_classes) as Map;
  final g = JsonSerializerGenerator();
  final classesCode = g.generateClasses(classes);
  final values = {
    'classes': classesCode,
  };

  var source = g.render(_template, values);
  source = g.format(source);
  File('bin/stackoverflow.dart').writeAsStringSync(source);
}

const _classes = r'''
Example:
  fields:
    a:
      type: String
      deserialize: "(x){ return x == null ? '0' : '$x'; }"
    b:
      type: List<String>
      deserialize: "(x){ return x == null ? <String>[] : (x as List).map((e) => e == null ? '0' : '$x').toList(); }"
''';

const _template = r'''
{{classes}}
''';
```

The same problem.
Even a little more code is required, as "deserialize" is not post-processing, but a complete implementation of a custom deserialization processing.

```dart
class Example {
  Example({required this.a, required this.b});

  factory Example.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Example(
      a: (x) {
        return x == null ? '0' : '$x';
      }(json['a']),
      b: (x) {
        return x == null
            ? <String>[]
            : (x as List).map((e) => e == null ? '0' : '$x').toList();
      }(json['b']),
    );
  }

  final String a;

  final List<String> b;

  static List<Example> fromJsonList(List json) {
    return json.map((e) => Example.fromJson(e as Map)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'a': a,
      'b': b,
    };
  }

  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> toJsonList(List<Example> list) {
    return list.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
  }
}
```